# Expressing one Metric in terms of another

Tags: manifolds

I was wondering if someone could check if I'm doing this correctly. I am given the stereographic projection map from $S^3\backslash \{(0,0,0,1)\}\rightarrow R^3$ $u_i=\frac{x_i}{1-x_4}$ and asked to express the metric $\sum_{i=1}^4 dx_i^2$ in the form $f(u_1, u_2, u_3) (du_1^2+du_2^2+du_3^2)$. The work that I've done so far is below, but I dont seem to be getting the correct form. I was hoping someone could helpj me to see where I'm going wrong:

Let the variable $j$ range over the values $1,2,3$ and $i$ over the values $1,2,3,4$ so that 
\begin{equation}
\sum x_i^2=1 \label{1}
\end{equation}
Given that 
\begin{equation}
u_j=\frac{x_j}{1-x_4} \label{2}
\end{equation}
we find, upon combining (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}), that 
$$\sum u_j^2=\frac{\sum x_i^2 -x_4^2}{(1-x_4)^2}=\frac{1+x_4}{1-x_4} $$
which implies
\begin{equation}
x_4=\frac{\sum u_j^2-1}{\sum u_j^2+1} =\frac{\sum u_j^2+1-2}{\sum u_j^2+1}=1-\frac{2}{\sum u_j^2+1}  \label{3}
\end{equation}
Hence

\begin{align*}
dx_4&=\sum \frac{\partial x_4}{\partial u_j }du_j\\
&=\frac{\sum 4u_jdu_j}{\left(\sum u_j^2+1\right)^2}
\end{align*}

hence

\begin{align}
dx_4^2&=\left(\frac{4\sum u_jdu_j}{\sum u_j^2+1}\right)^2\\
%&=\frac{16 \sum u_j^2du_j^2+32e_2(u_jdu_j)}{\left(\sum u_j^2+1    \right)^2} \label{5}\\
\end{align}
 Next note that (\ref{2}) gives 
\begin{align*}
dx_j&=\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial u_j}du_j\\
&=(1-x_4)du_j
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align}
dx_j^2&=(1-x_4)^2du_j^2 \label{4}
\end{align}
and, combining (\ref{3}) and (\ref{4}), we obtain 
\begin{align*}
dx_j^2=\frac{4u_jdu_j^2}{\left( \sum u_j^2+1  \right)^2}
\end{align*}
finally, (\ref{5}) and (\ref{4}) imply 
\begin{align*}
\sum dx_i^2 &=\sum dx_j^2+dx_4^2\\
&=\frac{4\sum u_jdu_j^2+\left(  4\sum u_jdu_j  \right)^2}{\left( \sum u_j^2+1  \right)^2}\\
&=\frac{4\sum u_j du_j^2+16\sum u_jdu_j\sum u_j du_j}{\left(\sum u_j^2+1\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{4\sum u_j du_j^2+16\left( \sum u_j^2du_j^2 +2e_2(u_j du_j) \right)}{\left(\sum u_j^2+1\right)^2}\\
%&= \frac{\sum 4u_jdu_j+16 \sum {u_j}^2du_j^2+32e_2(u_jdu_j)}{\left( \sum u_j^2+1  \right)^2}\\
%&= \frac{\sum 4u_jdu_j\left(1+4 \sum {u_j}^2du_j^2 \right)+32e_2(u_jdu_j)}{\left( \sum u_j^2+1  \right)^2}
\end{align*}
where $e_2(\alpha_j)$ denotes the elementary symmetric polynomial consisting of all products of distinct pairs of the symbols $\alpha_i$ (e.g. $e_2(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)=\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_3$)

This last expression is nasty and seems incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you turn to the computation of $dx_j$ for $j\ne4$, note that $x_j=(1-x_4)u_j$ hence $$dx_j=(1-x_4)du_j-u_jdx_4$$ instead of $dx_j=(1-x_4)du_j$, hence $$dx^2=\sum_{j=1}^4dx_j^2$$ is actually $$dx^2=dx_4^2+(1-x_4)^2\sum_{j=1}^3du_j^2+\sum_{j=1}^3u_j^2dx_4^2-2(1-x_4)\sum_{j=1}^3u_jdu_jdx_4$$  Now use $$dx_4=(1-x_4)^2dv$$ with the shorthand $$dv=\sum_{j=1}^3u_jdu_j$$ and the identity already in your post saying that $$\sum_{j=1}^3u_j^2=\sum_{j=1}^3\frac{x_j^2}{(1-x_4)^2}=\frac{1-x_4^2}{(1-x_4)^2}=\frac{1+x_4}{1-x_4}$$ to deduce ...

Comment: $$dx^2=(1-x_4)^4dv^2+(1-x_4)^2\sum_{j=1}^3du_j^2+(1-x_4^2)(1-x_4)^2dv^2-2(1-x_4)^3dv^2$$ which simplifies into $$dx^2=(1-x_4)^2\sum_{j=1}^3du_j^2=\ldots$$